# Is heat combinded damage also considered heat damage?

Tags: warframe

For example: Ember's Accelerant mutliplies heat damage. But does it also multiply with gas (heat+toxin), blast (heat+cold) or radiation (heat+electricity) damage? Maybe only the heat fraction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not since the combined elements create a completely new and "separate" type of damage. Unfortunately the only place I've been able to find information on this is the comment section on the wiki for accelerant.

Comment: That would mean that for using Ember's accelerant pure heat damage is key then?!

Comment: For it to be most effective, yes. You can test out different combinations in game, but this is what I've found so far.